# Entering UK for two short visits within a month (non EU)

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, us-citizens, repeat-visits

I entered the UK last week for about 21 hours, to deliver a talk in London and slept in a hotel before leaving the country again the following morning. I live in an EU country but I am a national of the US.

Next week, I have tickets to fly to the UK to spend Christmas with my best friend and her family.

I used to live in the UK for 5 years with a student visa, and so I was asked the last time I entered (last week) whether I still have 'any interests' in the UK. I said that I did not, however now I"m worried I said the wrong thing, as my friends are still in the UK and I intend to visit them sometimes. But I don't live there and I go a few times per year (a conference, a talk, and Christmas in 2016, since I left the UK in October 2015).

As an aside, I also had a small problem in 2015 (I was prevented from entering on my student visa after graduation. My intention had been to pack up my stuff and leave by the expiry of my visa which I did. I was informed that since I graduated, my visa was invalid even though it didn't expire for several months. They let me in because I showed them my contract for the job I was starting in a few months, in another country, and because I genuinely had no idea that my visa would become invalid after graduation even if it had 3 months more validity.)

I know that the UK ECOs are on the look-out for people living secretly in the UK. That isn't me, but I can understand why two trips in short succession might look that way.

Is this going to flag the ECO and is there any way I can ameliorate the situation so I can visit my friend?

Comment: Do any of your LTE stamps have anything handwritten on them other than the IO's initials? Also as you are in the EU, will you be arriving at City Airport?

Comment: Hi! I'm flying into Manchester. I did fly into LCY last time, though. I looked at my passport, there are no hand-written remarks from the trip last week. My 'problem' entry stamp from July 2015 has "PDL [numbers]" written above a stamp which says "entry clearance for six months".

Comment: That's fine, you're good to go. Play it straight up that you are maintaining relationships with friends for the holz and have your contract at the ready. I don't see a big problem.

Comment: OK, great. I have a few copies of my contract in France and I have felt like it's good to bring that since I needed it another time. So it's simple enough to bring one. Thank you for your help, I feel better now!

Comment: Please wait for someone who wants rep to come along and add an 'official' answer below that tells you the same thing and then ACCEPT it, thanks

Comment: Hey @GayotFow, nobody else seems to have answered yet. Would you like to post an answer? Otherwise, I can post my result (entered UK fine) as an answer with reference to your text in the comments. Up to you, I really don't mind. Just want to have an answer for future people one way or the other.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that they stamped my passport with an entry for December 23, 2018. Manchester is the future.

Comment: Please go ahead and add your answer on personal experience. Ping me when it's ready, thanks!

Comment: @GayotFow ping!

Comment: +1, well done and thanks for the personal experience! Always great to have both theory and practice along side each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @GayotFow indicated in their response, everything was fine and I was granted entry without problem.

The ECO asked:

- How long I would be in the country and why I was visiting (answered)
- Where I would be returning to afterward, and what I'm doing there (since it's not my country of birth). (answered)

The ECO noted my previous stay and stamped my passport right next to the stamp from earlier in the month. Strangely with a stamp indicating Dec 2018 entry. The whole process took about 2 minutes.

Per Gayot Fow's recommendation, I did bring a copy of my work contract in my current country, to show that I have major reason to return as stated. It was never necessary but good to have anyway.